# Changing DC voltage through an inductor

Tags: inductor

What happens if I apply such changing DC signals (Voltage)  to the inductor on one end?

I read somewhere that by applying such signals on one end of the inductor will result in the average values of those signals on the other end of the inductor.

Is it so? What is the reason for that if what I read is true?

[image: diagram showing sine, square, triangular and sawtooth waveforms]

Image source: [MADPCB - What's Triangular Wave](https://madpcb.com/glossary/triangular-wave/)

Comment: Where did you read that and what was the context? If you take an inductor and apply those waveforms on one end, you will see the exact same waveform at the other end.

Comment: Somewhere. I dont remember

Comment: An inductor is a voltage-to-current integrator (of course, the other end should be grounded). In contrast, a capacitor is a current-to-voltage integrator.

Comment: As tobalt hints, a signal on one terminal of a component, with the other terminals undefined, isn't meaningful. An inductor might do things as you suggest *when embedded in a circuit*, but that circuit must be defined.

Comment: Let's say that the other end is connected to a capacitor.

Comment: @Alex, well if connected to a capacitor and assuming a common ground, it will tend to follow the source waveform for frequencies below the LC resonant freq. Above that it will tend to a decreasing amplitude wave approaching zero. Near resonance, it can get, shall we say, interesting.

Comment: @Alex - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help, I found what I believe to be the source webpage link & added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: You can (and actual engineers do!) think of an inductor as a frequency-dependent resistor. It has low resistance to low-frequency signals and high resistance to high-frequency signals. You can use this to make a frequency-dependent voltage divider, that reduces low voltages, but just like you need two resistors to make a voltage divider, you need at least an inductor and a resistor to make a frequency-dependent one. (Can also be done with a resistor and a capacitor, and that way is usually smaller and cheaper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I read somewhere that by applying such signals on one end of the
> inductor will result in the average values of those signals on the
> other end of the inductor.*

That can well present how a whole circuit works when the inductor is a part of a lowpass filter and the frequency range of the input signals is limited so that there's a DC component plus some AC at so high frequency that the filter kills the AC. The average i.e. the DC component passes through the inductor.

But the explanation is pure nonsense if the only component is the inductor alone plus a voltage.

Like all 2 terminal circuit elements also inductors have an operating law which tells what current is caused through the inductor when one connects a known voltage between its terminals. Or reversely: What's the voltage between the terminals when one knows how the current through the inductor varies along the time.

For resistors such law is I = U/R, but the law for inductors is a differential equation. Start your studies of it from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor. Or get a book of physics which fits your level of math knowledge.

Also here in EE StackExchange exists numerous old discussion about inductors, induction and what inductors do in circuits - for ex. induce voltages or brake current changes. Some of them try to explain how the effect of the mentioned voltage vs. current differential equation appears in practice.

Answer (score 2):

What you call a "changing DC signal" is just the sum of a DC signal (the long-term average) and an AC signal (the difference between the instantaneous value and the long-term average). An inductor is linear, so its response is the sum of the response to those two components. The response to the DC component is that it's passed unchanged. The response to the AC component is a positive reactance, which is the thing you can read about in every resource on inductors ever. You should be able to figure everything else out from there.